# Centering the form inside div

Tags: css

How can I get the form centered, aligned with the submit button underneath it inside div?  http://www.magnixsolutions.com/dev/test/test.html

```
.containerForm {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 65px;    
}
.containerSecuImgs {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;   
}
```

Also the two images underneath will not let me move up little bit after putting padding-bottom: 20px; What did I do wrong?

Comment: what you are asking for isn't clear

Comment: For the images, add `position:relative;bottom:20px;` to the `.containerSecuImgs`. As for the first part, I don't quite understand what do you want. Be more specific.

Comment: flagged as very low quality

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the label and input groups with a wrapper element (such as a div), and give that a margin of `0 auto` to center it. Inside that wrapper element you can float your labels and inputs as needed.

Here's an example I knocked up for you: http://jsfiddle.net/BqEa8/

Comment: Thank you for the link, but thats not what I meant. The whole form will need to be centered, aligned with the submit button underneath it. Right now it is aligned to the left as you can tell on the webpage. I tried text-align: center; in the .well class and that didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Applying `margin: 0px auto;` will position html elements to the center of the browser window.

Try out adding this to your css:

```
.well label {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Hope it will help you to solve the center aligning issue

Answer (score 0):

add this class to div:

```
.centerxa {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```